# Dockerized PostgreSQL log to both /log & `docker logs`?

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, logging, postgresql-11

My PostgreSQL 11.6 is running inside a Docker container based on an [existing image](https://hub.docker.com/r/timescale/timescaledb/). Running `docker logs my-postgres` shows the log messages produced by the dockerized PostgreSQL instance.

**Problem:** I am trying to set up the system such that PostgreSQL logs the messages to a log file in `/var/lib/postgresql/data/log` and still be able to show the log messages when you run `docker logs my-postgres`.

Logging to a file works when `/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf` was modified to have the following:

```
log_collector = on
log_directory = 'log'
log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'
log_rotation_age = 1d
log_rotation_size = 100MB
```

However, running `docker logs my-postgres` now shows

```
2020-02-23 18:01:49.388 UTC [1] LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process
2020-02-23 18:01:49.388 UTC [1] HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "log".
```

and new log messages no longer appear here.

Is it possible to log to the log file and also show the same log messages in `docker logs my-postgres`?

---

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    my-postgres:
        container_name: my-postgres
        image: timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg11
        ports:
        - 5432:5432
```

Answer (score 2):

By default docker uses `json-file` logging driver. This driver saves everything from container's `stdout` and `stderr` into `/var/lib/docker/containers/<container-id>/<container-id>-json.log` on your docker host. The `docker logs` command just reads from that file. By default postgresql logs into stderr `#log_destination = 'stderr'`

You enabled the logging collector which catches the logs sent to stderr and saves them into filesystem instead. This is the reason why you don't see them anymore in `docker logs` output. I don't see anywhere in postgresql documentation how to send logs both to file and stderr. I'm no expert on psql though.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/runtime-config-logging.html

Containers should log into stderr and stdout. Configure the cont. process to log into file inside container's filesystem is considered bad practice. You will lose the filesystem when container dies unless you attach the folder as volume.

If you insist your only chance is to change config line `log_filename` into something static like `postgresql.log` and create symbolic link (and rewrite the `postgresql.log` file created by psql) pointing it to it to stderr `ln -fs /dev/stderr /var/lib/postgresql/data/log/postgresql.log`.

I haven't tested the solution and I have certain doubts about loggin collector and its log_rotate capabilities. I have no idea what happens with `postgresql.log` when log file is rotated. Maybe it's copied and original file deleted / recreated by postgres and you'll lose your link. You can try to disable `log_truncate_on_rotation` boolean to overcome this but I'm not sure if this would help tbh.

Comment: just realized the solution provided would not help you keep the files in containers filesystem anyway.. only in stdout

In that case I don't see anyway how to have them on filesystem and stderr at once. I don't think it's possible.